# addprefix in MAKE doesn't work correctly when -e is used as prefix

Tags: makefile

I encounter a strange behavior of `addprefix` with -e. The expected -e for the first word is not added. Here's the makefile to reproduce it.

```
a := file1 file2 file3
b := $(addprefix -s , $(a))
c := $(addprefix -e , $(a))
all:
    @echo $(b)
    @echo $(c)
```

Result:

```
-s file1 -s file2 -s file3
file1 -e file2 -e file3
```

Is it a bug or something is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never use `echo` to print any string that is not just simple text that you know contains no starting dash characters.  The `echo` command is not really standardized and there are a lot of versions, some of which accept options and some of which don't.

On your system, the `echo` command accepts a `-e` option so when you use `echo -e file -e file2 -e file3` echo eats the first `-e`.

You can use:

```
all:
        @printf '%s\n' '$(b)'
        @printf '%s\n' '$(c)'
```

to be portable.  Or you can use make's built-in functions:

```
all:
        $(info $(b))
        $(info $(c))
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.